# How do I return to the main site from Meta?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

The redesigned all-new top bar has a *Help* dropdown menu. There's a *Meta* item in there. That's a great thing, because now you can access Meta easily.

[image: Help dropdown]

On Meta SuperUser it's changing into *What's Meta*:

[image: Meta Help dropdown]

**How do I return to the main site from Meta (without typing the URL manually)?**

I can visit my profile and click *main user*, but that's not something you would do intuitively. Am I missing something? If not, then I think appropriate item should be added to the *Help* menu (so you can return from Meta the same way you got there).

Comment: If you click on "What's Meta?" it does send you back to the [main site](http://superuser.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 6):

Click *Stack Exchange*, then *Super User*.

[image: Screenshot]

---

#### Now a new item has been added to meta's *help* menu:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that one. But I stand my point, the Help menu is a good place for a main page link.

Comment: @gronostaj The main site has nothing to do with help, it would only be there to mirror the main site's link. Meta OTOH is all about getting help and explanations.

Comment: You are right, but imagine you are a new user and you got to Meta through the Help menu. Where would you look for the link back to the main site?

Answer (score 2):

**Use your web browser's built-in features.**

From my Firefox Bookmarks Toolbar:

[image]

(RA = Root Access chat)

Comment: I'm looking from a perspective of a new user, I think that's at least 95% of visitors. When they get to Meta for the first time, there should be an intuitive way to return to SU.